# Referencing the [condition] field of an excel IF statement within the [value_if_true] statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have been using IF statements in excel, some of which are becoming long a repetitious.

The [condition], [value if true] and [value_if_false] fields all contain the same long expression which seems redundant. For example, many of the functions look like this:

```
=IF( [long_expression] > 130 , 3*[long_expression]^2 , 2*[long_expression]^3 )
```

Is there a way to reduce the repetition within these statements by referencing the condition directly from the other two fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 3 options and it depends:

- if it's a single value, go with Gary's suggestion and make a Name for it (or if you don't like names put it in a cell and reference that).
- if your `IF` statement is used in a column of data you can insert an additional column, do the calculation there (, possibly hide it) and reference that.
- if you are using VBA and the formula is only used to calculate the values once and then paste as values then consider putting the calculation in VBA.

As there is no way to define variables in the formulas you cannot make a direct reference to the expression. The only shortcuts introduced in newer versions of Excel are `IFERROR` and `IFNA` (and maybe some others) which let you write e.g.

```
IF(ISERROR([possible_div_0_expression]),0,[possible_div_0_expression])
```

as

```
IFERROR([possible_div_0_expression],0)
```

Comment: Yeah actually the behaviour of the IFERROR function is what got me thinking of this possibility in the first place; the idea that you can default to what is expressed in the condition. Unfortunate that there isn't slightly more intricacy.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.  Excel is not intended to be used as a programming language.  It's nice that they allow some conditional formulas at all.  It gets even messier when you have to nest many IF statements together to make the equivelent of a CASE statement.

If you want to do some cleaner formulas, you may have to consider a VB macro.

Comment: A macro would be a good solution, although I'm trying to implement something that other users can easily decode just by looking at it. I'm trying to stay close to the realm of familiarity here for the sake of others, though I agree macros are best for this type of application.

Comment: I answered the way I did, because I've run into this sort of thing before.  I've got some sheets that have outragously long, nested IF statements, just to do something that would seem simple.  The other good suggestion (on top of what other's have said), is to split your forumulas up across fields.  Rather than trying to do everything in one formula, spread the steps out across a few.  That does help to keep things easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **Name** feature in the **Formulas** tab.  Pick a name like **BigGuy** and assign it a formula like:

```
=(A1+A77)/(B23+B77)
```

and then:

```
=IF( BigGuy > 130 , 3*BigGuy^2 , 2*BigGuy^3 )
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the reason I have these large IF statements is to avoid including extra columns in the sheet. I have a column of these IF statements and the condition is a function of the row in this case, i.e. not a single constant.